# Why doesn't this rsyslog conf file cause recursion?

Tags: linux, rsyslog, rsyslogd

I'm studying `rsyslog` by a combination of man pages, online reading, and experimenting. I'd like to understand why the following does not result in infinite recursion:

From terminal 1:

```
$ cat /etc/rsyslog.d/dummy.conf 
# dummy.conf
local7.*                                  @127.0.0.1
&                                         |/tmp/foopipe

$ sudo systemctl restart rsyslog

$ cat < /tmp/foopipe
```

From terminal 2:

```
$ logger -p local7.info "Test 111"
```

After the above, the text "`2018-07-16T18:09:50.866760-07:00 localhost user: Test 111`" appears in terminal 1. But only one line of it appears; i.e. not multiple copies, and not an infinite flood.

I'm still pretty inexperienced with `rsyslog` configuration files, so I'm piecing things together from my rudimentary understanding. I thought that my `dummy.conf` file would instruct `rsyslog` to send my `local.info` syslog to the named pipe as well as forward the syslog to 127.0.0.1.

Assuming the latter does occur...I'm not real clear what happens next, but I imagined that `rsyslog` would receive the `local.info` syslog from the UDP/TCP socket it listens at, then again apply the `dummy.conf` rules which would again instruct rsyslog to send the syslog to the pipe as well as forward 127.0.0.1...thus infinite recursion.

Am I missing something? Or does `rsyslog` have smarts built into it to thwart infinite recursion of this type?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you're running into [this option](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsconf1_repeatedmsgreduction.html):

```
$RepeatedMsgReduction on
```

You may have this enabled.

#### References

- [Dynamically remove duplicate log messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28970299/dynamically-remove-duplicate-log-messages)

Comment: There's something a bit more subtle going on here; what you pointed out is relevant, but seems to only be part of the story. I will post a new question with updated information.

Comment: Created this new question in case you're able offer insight there: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/456827/why-does-rsyslog-only-infinitely-recurse-when-listening-with-udp